# Assigning specific/explicit memory locations to my objects

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

Can i make an object in C++ specifying its memory address explicitly? This is because i am having separate ids for each of my entities (the objects). So if i can do this, i will be able to traverse through all my objects by mere pointer additions. 
Consider:
I have an object with memory location x.
I want to create the next object with memory location x+(the unique id of the next object)*K 
where K is the constant gap between two objects(say)

Comment: you can preserve a memory block: data = new Object[100]. 100 objects will be near each other

Comment: @Andrew: Or better still, `std::vector<Object>(100)`, so you don't have to remember to delete it.

Comment: If I understand the question, you don't actually want to specify the address of each object; you just want them to be stored consecutively in memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the memory using the placement `new` operator.

> So if i can do this, i will be able to traverse through all my objects by mere pointer additions.

Not really. **Disregard answers that tell you to do this!** You can't do pointer arithmetics outside of an array. Just because you have 2 objects `o1` and `o2`, one located at `0x4` and the other at `0x5`, it doesn't mean that `&o1 + 1` will yield `&o2`. In fact, it's undefined behavior.

For this to work as expected, you can allocate the memory dynamically, or, better yet, use a `std::vector` and use iterators. (that's what they are for)

Comment: Suppose I use this vector. Then as an when the octs are created, i'll add them to the vector in the order they are created. In that case, will i be able to traverse all the objects in sequence of their creation by pointer additions?

Comment: @AakashAnuj yes. If you have `vector<Obj> x;`, `x[0]` will give you the first object that was added to the vector, `x[1]` the second, and so on. You don't even need to use pointer additions. You can use a `std::vector<Obj>::iterator` if you're keen on it.

Comment: Grumpiness? Anyway, it is worth noting that when you reach the limits of your preallocated region of memory, `std::vector` will sort out reallocation, freeing of old memort and copying of instances for you. This is almost always a good thing, *unless you are keeping pointers to other members of the vector in scope*. So don't do that. If you must, then either a) never add new elements to the vector or b) use a fixed-length `std::array`.

Comment: @Rook or use a fixed-length `std::vector`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I had no idea such a thing existed! I guess it would be useful on systems which lack Boost or C++11.

Comment: Creating the vector will be an averhead to the memory and will not be memory efficient according to me. Because as per i get it, x[0] will be a pointer to the 1st object, x[1] to the second and so on. That will be the same as having a pointer to each of the objects.

Comment: @AakashAnuj `x[0]` **is** the object, not a pointer to it. There's no memory overhead.

Comment: So will the vector ensure that the objects have a contiguous memory location even though they are created at an arbitrary instance in the program?

Comment: @AakashAnuj yes, internally, a `std::vector` guarantees continuous memory allocation.

Comment: I have assigned my objects the ids 1,2,3,4,...... sequentially but they are not created in the same order. They are created using recursion, so the order is not 1,2,3,4..So by using their ids, can i make traversals through them with as less pointers as possible? Do suggest me any other method to do that if possible ( one straightforward method is to have a pointer to each of the objects, but it is of a great memory overhead )

Comment: @AakashAnuj you can preallocate the vector - `std::vector<Obj> objects(100)` and then assign values randomly - `objects[3] = thirdObject; objects[2] = secondObject;` and so on.

Comment: My point is not only to store any object in contiguous memory locations, but to store it sequentially in a contiguous memory location. So even if i use std:vector , the order in which the elements get added to the vector will not be sequential. Or can we even make the object 8 occupy exactly x[7] even if the elements before it are not created?

Answer (score -1):

C++ placement new operator does what you want. Just make sure you allocate them enough memory.

See: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

The example from above link:

```
char memory[sizeof(Fred)];
void* place = memory;

Fred* f = new(place) Fred();
```

Comment: See my comment to Black's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Andrews answer and allocate an array of Objects.

In C++, You can also use a special form of the new operator to create an object at a preallocated address:

```
char memory[sizeof(MyClass[100])]; // memory for an array of 100 MyClass-objects

// Cast to MyClass-Array to let the compiler calculate
// the start addresses of the array elements.
MyClass * array = reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(memory);

// create object with index 5
MyClass * pointerToSixthEntry= new (&array[5]) MyClass();

// Use the object by its index (no pointer arithmetic needed)
array[5].sayHelloWorld();
```

This is called [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

It is ugly and I wouldn't do it. If it's not really memory/runtime critical, You could think about using a STL map with the index as key. As a positive side effect, You get the tracking of used/unused IDs for free.

Using a preallocated vector might also help. Check Luchian's answers and comments.

Comment: Have you read the whole question? `So if i can do this, i will be able to traverse through all my objects by mere pointer additions.` using placement new doesn't help.

Comment: I have read the whole question. Of course, the answer is simplified. Use Andrew's answer, if You want all objects created at once. Use placement new to create them _at the correct address in the array_ anytime You want. Anyway, imho C++ objects and pointer arithmetics do not mix well.

Comment: Not only is it simplified, it's dangerous, because most probably using placement new will appear to work in continuous memory, but it's in fact undefined behavior.

Comment: See, my basic problem is that i have some objects which have a unique id. I want to use that id in their address so that i can use pointer arithmetic to use them.

Comment: I have assigned my objects the ids 1,2,3,4,...... sequentially but they are not created in the same order. They are created using recursion, so the order is not 1,2,3,4..So by using their ids, can i make traversals through them with as less pointers as possible? Do suggest me any other method to do that if possible ( one straightforward method is to have a pointer to each of the objects, but it is of a great memory overhead )

Comment: I modified my answer to make my intention clear. My answer also shows how to access the object without the need for pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Please reply to the question I asked above

Comment: The answer to Your question is: Use std::vector with preallocation. It's described in Luchian's comment above: `std::vector<Obj> objects(100)`

Answer (score -1):

Qestion on your ids, are these also consecutive and no missing values?

if so

I think the std::map suits your needs,
the keys (your ids) are sorted, (just insert within recursion) 
and you have the ability to use iterators (pointer arithmetic).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/