# c++ vector not allocating contiguous memory

Tags: c++, vector

The std :: vector in C++ stores the objects in contiguous memory locations. 
But when I print the address, I find that this does not happen.
Please let me know why.
The code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class a
{

     int val1;

};
vector<a> records(10);
int main()
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<12;i++)
         cerr<<"address"<<i<<"="<<&records[i]<<endl;
}
```

The output I get is not contiguous in memory.

Comment: The output i get is :address0=0xde0010
address1=0xde0014
address2=0xde0018
address3=0xde001c
address4=0xde0020
address5=0xde0024
address6=0xde0028
address7=0xde002c
address8=0xde0030
address9=0xde0034

Comment: @AakashAnuj, Seems fine to me. Your struct contains one `int`, which is 4 bytes, like most.

Comment: and why do you iterate in range (0, 11) when the size of vector is 10?

Comment: after 18, i get 1c? it should have been address3=0xde0022 right?

Comment: nope ... 0x18 + 0x4 = 0x1c ...

Comment: @AakashAnuj, Addresses are typically displayed in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) form, as evident by the leading `0x`.

Comment: Please read a bit about numeration bases - hexa, decimal, binary

Comment: I already specified yesterday that it does - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227406/assigning-specific-explicit-memory-locations-to-my-objects

Answer (score 7):

First of all the memory addressed you show are contiguous - simply the size of an integer is 4 bytes on your system it seems.

Also your vector is of size 10 and you print the addresses up to 12. This is not a problem thanks to the memory allocation strategy of a vector, though. Just keep in mind you should be more careful.

Answer (score 3):

The addresses will be offset from each other by the size of class A.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your system, every `int` has a size of 4 bytes.

Comment: not true. It is implementation defined. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: @Andrew it's generally a better idea to improve the answer, unless the author disagrees with it. And you already got the rep for that.